# With multiple yes/no radio buttons, do I have to create each instance?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I'm trying to make an app with a panel where it asks a question (whether an image contains humans, cars, or other objects... and more). Each question is answered with yes/no. I didn't want to make JRadioButton for each of the 'yes's and 'no's. So I tried to add the same Radio Button multiple times but it doesn't work (See below).

```java
contentsPanel = new JPanel();
contentsHumans = new JLabel("Humans? ");
contentsCars = new JLabel("Cars? ");
contentsOtherObjects = new JLabel("Other Objects? ");

yes = new JRadioButton("Yes"); 
no = new JRadioButton("No");
binaryAnswer = new ButtonGroup();
binaryAnswer.add(yes);
binaryAnswer.add(no);

contentsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                 BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Image contains... "));
contentsPanel.add(contentsHumans);
contentsPanel.add(yes); contentsPanel.add(no);
contentsPanel.add(contentsCars);
contentsPanel.add(yes); contentsPanel.add(no);
contentsPanel.add(contentsOtherObjects);
contentsPanel.add(yes); contentsPanel.add(no);
```

Do I have to separately create `y1 = new JRadioButton("Yes");`, `y2 = new JRadioButton("Yes");`, etc., for all my 'yes's and 'no's?? I can definitely copy and paste to do that but I was wondering if there is any other way.

Here's the image of current output:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of what you would expect the UI to look like (and the current result?). Strictly speaking there are multiple ways to achieve this (a yes/no button that would take the current context of the UI, or a yes/no button that's generated within a method that makes new panes, etc)

Comment: Use a method that adds two radiobuttons in a buttongroup. Copying and pasting code is sign of repetitive code, which is almost always improvable.

Comment: You need to create new instances of the buttons.  Otherwise, pressing one is the same as pressing all.  But you can do this in a loop.  And if you update required listeners during creation you don't even need to keep the button fields around.  Using a method to create buttons is a common practice.